# CSS Floats: 3 floated boxes

Tags: css, box

I am having trouble with some floated boxes in CSS.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="one">One</div>
<div class="two">Two</div>
<div class="tre">Three - The HTML structure should stay like this, but this box should be starting to the left of the red box.</div>
</div>
```

Here is the pen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myKzMd

I want the left green box to start on the same height as the red one. HTML structure should stay as is.
Thanks,
Sascha

Comment: Don’t float the third/green box …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code below will get the result you want.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="tre">Three - The HTML structure should stay like this, but this box should be starting to the left of the red box.</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  height:400px;
  border: 5px solid green;
}
.one {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.two {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
}
.tre {
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  width: 40%;
}
```

**EDIT:** Updated the answer with full code, to avoid confusing, since OP has updated the demo in the question. So no float on `.tre` would be the best solution to me.

Comment: Yeah, that worked too. Same as float: none I assume. I cannot yet upvote sadly :(

Answer (score 1):

```
.tre {
  float: left;
 }
```

Dont forget to put overflow:hidden in parent div ie .container because once you float the child elements you have to put overflow:hidden in its

Comment: Yeah, that is a good hint! Wish there would be a better solution than overflow: hidden. Sometimes, I have content (i.e. tooltips), that get cut-off because of that.

Comment: ya that's true my friend

Answer (score 0):

try this out :

```
.container {
  height:400px;
  border: 5px solid green;
}
.one {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
  margin-left:40%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.two {
   height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
}
.tre {
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  width: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
  height:400px;
  border: 5px solid green;
}

.one {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
}

.two, .three {
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
  float:right;
}

.two {
  background: yellow;
}

.three {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your structure like below...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="tre">Three - The HTML structure should stay like this, but this box should be starting to the left of the red box.</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
</div>
```